# Angular: RxStomp Watch, Configure, Activate Method

Tags: angular, websocket, stomp, stompjs

In Stomp we used these mehtods:

```
initUserEvents() {

this.stompService.startConnect().then(() => {
      this.stompService.done('init');

this.stompService.subsribe('/channel/login', res => {
      if (res.username !== this.username) {

        this.newConnectedAccounts.push(res.username);
```

right now I'm working with RxStomp and I can't figure out the right way to use these "replacement" methods:

```
initUserEvents() {

this.stompService.configure();
    this.stompService.activate(){

    this.stompService.watch('/channel/login', res => {
      if (res.username !== this.username) {
        this.newConnectedAccounts.push(res.username);
```

The error I'm getting is:
**TS2345: Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StompHeaders'.   Index signature is missing in type '(res: any) => void'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the RxStomp documentation. It says:

> The key difference is that it exposes operations as RxJS Observables. For example when a STOMP endpoint is subscribed it returns an Observable that will stream all received messages.
>
> With exception of beforeConnect, functionality related to all callbacks in [@stomp/stompjs Client](https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html) is exposed as Observables/Subjects/BehaviorSubjects.

In other words, you don't pass a callback to the [`watch`](https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/RxStomp.html#watch) method. It returns an [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) you can use to get the messages.

The RxStomp API expects you to pass in headers to the `watch` method, not a callback. That's why it's telling you specifically:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StompHeaders'.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me a lot. Last question: Do you may have any examples?